# Append one value from array of lists - react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

This API require me to send some data comma separated, when handling the user input I use checkboxes like so

```
   <SelectMultiple
      items={dairy}
      selectedItems={this.state.selectedIngredients}
      onSelectionsChange={this.onSelectionsChange} />
```

I can definitely see the inputs if I render selectedIngredients on a FlatList (using item.value) but when I try to print the actual url I am working with I got this [object,Object]

I used `this.state.selectedIngredients` in the view, here is the result:

> url.com/api/?=[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Inside my `search` function I use that code to handle user inputs:

```
  const { selectedIngredients } = this.state;
  let url = "url.com/api/?i=" + selectedIngredients
```

In the documentation of the library they say the selected items is type array of string or { label, value } I used the method provided there to append the selected items:

```
  onSelectionsChange = (selectedIngredients) => {
    // selectedFruits is array of { label, value }
    this.setState({ selectedIngredients})
  }
```

I tried adding `.value` on both of them it didn't solve my problem. Could anyone one help please?

Console log this.state.selectedIngredients:

```
Array [
  Object {
    "label": "Goat cheese",
    "value": "Goat cheese",
  },
  Object {
    "label": "Cream cheese",
    "value": "Cream cheese",
  },
  Object {
    "label": "Butter",
    "value": "Butter",
  },
]
```

Comment: Some clarifications are needed. If `selectedIngredients` is an array of objects you cannot simply append it in the `url` string. That would indeed stringify the array of objects resuting in `[object,Object],[object,Object]`. What you might want is to use selectedIngredients.map() or any other for loop to create a correct string and append that string to the API url

Comment: @stilllife It's actually [object Object] and yes I have to do a loop and append one value in a list or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
selectedIngredients = [
 {
    "label": "Goat cheese",
    "value": "Goat cheese",
  },
  {
    "label": "Cream cheese",
    "value": "Cream cheese",
  },
  {
   "label": "Butter",
    "value": "Butter",
  },
]

let selectedValues = selectedIngredients.map((ingredient)=> ingredient.value)
let selectedValuesInString = selectedValues.join(',');
console.log(selectedValuesInString)
```

Comment: ValuesInString = Values.replace(' ',"+") Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit clumsy, but it'll give you a comma-separated string with no trailing comma.

```
const { selectedIngredients } = this.state;
let sep = "";
let selectedIngAsString = "";
selectedIngredients.forEach(s => {
   selectedIngAsString += sep + s.value;
   sep = ",";
});
let url = "url.com/api/?i=" + selectedIngAsString
```

See https://codesandbox.io/s/m5ynqw0jqp

Also, see Mohammed Ashfaq's for a much less clumsy answer.

Comment: I don't think you understand my problem

Comment: What does console.log(this.state.selectedIngredients) look like?

Comment: I added it to my post, can you help? I expect a string like selectedIngredients="goat,cream,butter"